# How to delete a non-responsive query component from search topology using PowerShell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, query, index-component

How to delete a stuck and not responding query component from a search topology in SharePoint 2010?

This query component worked fine before but it is not responding because the web front end server which hosts the query component was removed from SharePoint farm and added back.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the 2010 search service cmdlets, but from a high level I think all you need to do is create and activate a new topology with the correct components. Once activated you can remove the old topology

Comment: yes i can do the add new query component even i get the error and i can not, and this search service application has nearly 14,000,00 index count

Comment: What error do you get? When you activate a new topology the existing index will be merged into the new index. You won't lose items, though it will take a while and you should do it during a maintenance window